# Browser back button should keep on same page angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

through flag handle displaying of a component in angular, here the issue is when browser back clicks it redirect to a page which accesses earlier. Here the scenario is on browser back event page should be the same but this component should be hidden. Any suggestions on this.

```
       <div *ngIf="service.itemUnavailable">
          <app-item-unavailable [itemDetails]="itemDetails"></app-item-unavailable>
     </div>
```

Comment: here also I can make one separate page rather than component and redirect to there, but it will cost an API so avoiding right now.

Comment: Any reason not to use the router ?

Comment: to keep in same page you should have to use Angular router Guards.https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description sepcially CanActivate

Comment: To keep simple things, need to hide and show component only,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the angular router in order to do this.
If user goes to your app, then clicks on a link that redirect to an other page of your app, the back button will stay inside your app.
One page with many components and ngIf's sounds not that pretty.